# Using a variable inside an evaluate method

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

All i want is to use `itemCat` iniside evaluate method.
I have tried lots of ways but everyone fails!

This is my function:

```
clickDDown: async function(domCategories, itemCat)
{
  for (let catt of domCategories) {
    // Works but I need 'match' to be a variable (itemCat)
    const predicate = await catt.evaluate(x => x.textContent == 'match');

    // const predicate = await catt.evaluate(x => x.textContent == itemCat); // error: itemCat is not defined
    // const predicate = await catt.evaluate(x => x.textContent == itemCat, itemCat); // error: itemCat is not defined
    // const predicate = await catt.evaluate(x, itemCat => x.textContent == itemCat); // error: x is not defined
    // const predicate = await catt.evaluate(x, itemCat => x.textContent == itemCat, itemCat); // error: x is not defined

    // Doesn't throw error but predicate is always false
    // So i asume is reading/using some value incorrectly
    // const predicate = await catt.evaluate((x, itemCat) => {x.textContent == itemCat}, itemCat);

    if (predicate){
      console.log(`Clicked ${itemCat}`);
      await catt.click();
      break
    }
    else console.log(`Couldn't Clicked ${itemCat}`);
  };
}
```

And i use it in this context:

```
// Fetch the parent where all categories are (must be called after click on dropdown menu)
let parentDomCategories = await page.$(constants.cssMpCreateItemCategoryContainer);
// Fetch all categories in a list
let domCategories = await parentDomCategories.$$(constants.cssMpCreateItemCategoryAttr);

await utils.webAction(
  logger, 'Click Item Category Hogar', utils.clickDDown,
  domCategories, 'Hogar'  // Arguments of `clickDDown`
);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Because when i harcoded the match it works as expected, how can i use a variable?

Thanks in advanced ;)

Comment: I can't see any reason why you would be getting `itemCat is not defined`. It's a parameter to the function, so its scope includes all the nested functions.

Comment: @Barmar In Puppeteer, the `evaluate` callback is serialized, then run inside the browser console, so it doesn't have access to Node variables in the enclosing scope. It's a common gotcha that's specific to Puppeteer/Playwright and other web scraping libraries.

Comment: `const predicate = await catt.evaluate((x, itemCat) => {x.textContent == itemCat}, itemCat)` passes the variable correctly but remove the `{}` brackets so the expression is used as the return value.

Comment: Probably an easier way to do this is `if ((await catt.evaluate(x => x.textContent)) === itemCat)` so you don't have to pass anything into `evaluate`. `textContent` is totally serializable so the comparison is the same regardless of whether you do it in Node or the browser console. Taking a step back, there's [probably an even easier way to arrange this operation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676), but hard to make a recommendation since there's no context for what you're trying to accomplish or a complete, runnable example.

Comment: `x, itemCat => x.textContent == itemCat` is missing parentheses so it just evaluates `itemCat => ...` only as the one argument. Should be `(x, itemCat) => ...` as done in the last attempt.

Comment: `if ((await catt.evaluate(x => x.textContent)) === itemCat)` This code did it. Thank you so much again @ggorlen